# Getting error on secure websocket client in ruby?

Tags: ruby, openssl, jruby

When i am creating secure connection.

Getting error follows as,

**OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: certificate verify failed
connect at org/jruby/ext/openssl/SSLSocket.java:266**

Getting error on line : `@ssl_socket.connect`

**sample code :**

```
@socket  = TCPSocket.new(@uri.host, @port)
@ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
@ssl_context.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("certificate.crt"))
@ssl_context.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open("certificate.key"))
@ssl_context.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2_client
@ssl_context.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER 
@ssl_socket = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new(@socket, @ssl_context) 
@ssl_socket.sync_close = true
@ssl_socket.connect
```

any help on it, why am i getting such error on line `@ssl_socket.connect`

My aim is to connect with *secure websocket.*

Comment: How is your system setup. Are you sure the the system you try to connect to is up and running? Have you tried to connect without secure socket?

Comment: How did you generate your certificates? Are they signed by a root CA?

Comment: WS client running fine

Comment: any help for this?